# Express using acuityscheduling API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have tried a bunch of things with no success. Hope you guys can spare some knowledge.
I am using acuityscheduling's API to retreive appointments. their documentation says to do something like this:

on my express server:

```
  // https://acuityscheduling.com/api/v1/appointments?email=
  console.log(req.params);
  let email = req.params.email
  let apt;
  // res.send("appointments IS WORKING!!!")
  apt = acuity.request('/appointments?email='+email, function (err, res, appointments) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    apt = appointments;
    console.log(appointments)
  });
  console.log(apt);
  res.send(apt);
})
```

when i do a request using insomnia:
http://localhost:3000/appointments/email@gmail.com

```
  "uri": {
    "protocol": "https:",
    "slashes": true,
    "auth": null,
    "host": "acuityscheduling.com",
    "port": 443,
    "hostname": "acuityscheduling.com",
    "hash": null,
    "search": "?email=email@gmail.com",
    "query": "email=email@gmail.com",
    "pathname": "/api/v1/appointments",
    "path": "/api/v1/appointments?email=lornebatman@gmail.com",
    "href": "https://acuityscheduling.com/api/v1/appointments?email=lornebatman@gmail.com"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "AcuityScheduling-js/0.1.9",
    "host": "acuityscheduling.com",
    "authorization": "Basic MTQ1OTg2ODM6ZDdlZTA0YjljMjNjNTMwZTVmOGEzNzYzZmNkZDdmZWQ=",
    "accept": "application/json"
  }
}
```

but the output on my console returns the right data that I need.
Why would this be happening?
What am I missing to be able to retrieve the data from my frontend?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its general callback problem which is user mistake and the question is not specifically related to acuityscheduling API

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing things a bit and this worked.

```
  // https://acuityscheduling.com/api/v1/appointments?email=
  console.log(req.params);
  let email = req.params.email
  let apt;
  // res.send("appointments IS WORKING!!!")
  apt = acuity.request('/appointments?email='+email, function (err, response, appointments) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    apt = appointments;
    console.log(appointments)
    res.send(appointments);
  });
  console.log(apt);
  // res.send(apt);
})
```